# E-commerce - Usablity scenarios

Tags: usability-testing

I'm doing some usability scenarios and would like to clarify some doubts.

### Scenario - Add product to stock

> A new pair of shoes arrived from the supplier. Please publish the shoes
> information on the system.

Details that need to be filled:
Title, Price, Register date, Id, Description, Supplier, Supplier email, etc.

**Doubt:** Given that we want all the sellers to provide all the information mentioned above so as to keep the site and the info about all the products consistent, should the notification provided above read something like this?

*A new pair of shoes arrived from the supplier. Please publish the shoes information on the system. The name of the shoes is **"abcd"**, the price is **"50.90"**, the description is "....",*   and so on.

### Scenario - Where to put the login trigger?

**Doubt**: To buy a product and edit account info we need to login. Where should the *login* be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Login scenario**

I am answering this first because it is straightforward. Do not have the *edit account info* button/link present anywhere until the user has logged in. Having that button for a guest user is confusing.

For *Buy Product*, have the "Add to Cart" option present. When the user clicks on the "Checkout* or the "Buy Product" button from the cart. ask them to **Login to continue**

**Add product to stock scenario**

Keep the notification like this

> A new pair of shoes arrived from the supplier. Please publish the shoes information on the system.

### but...

Make the Title, Price, Register date, Id, Description, Supplier, Supplier email, etc. fields **MANDATORY**.

For **Description**, have a *minimum characters* limit.

That should promote more consistency throughout.